# Break one array in to two different array in php

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

my question is i want to break array in to two different array based upon start time  my array look like this

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [day_of_weeks] => Monday
            [start_time] => 6:00 PM
            [end_time] => 7:00 PM
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [day_of_weeks] => Tuesday
            [start_time] => 6:00 PM
            [end_time] => 7:00 PM
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [day_of_weeks] => Wednesday
            [start_time] => 6:00 PM
            [end_time] => 7:00 PM
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [day_of_weeks] => Friday
            [start_time] => 5:00 PM
            [end_time] => 6:00 PM
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [day_of_weeks] => Saturday
            [start_time] => 5:00 PM
            [end_time] => 6:00 PM
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [day_of_weeks] => Sunday
            [start_time] => 5:00 PM
            [end_time] => 6:00 PM
        )

)
```

something like this

```
Array(
    [0] => Array
    (
        [day_of_weeks] => Monday
        [day_of_weeks] => Tuesday
        [day_of_weeks] => Wednesday
        [start_time] => 6:00 PM
        [end_time] => 7:00 PM
    )
    [1] => Array
    (
        [day_of_weeks] => Friday
        [day_of_weeks] => Saturday
        [day_of_weeks] => Sunday
        [start_time] => 5:00 PM
        [end_time] => 6:00 PM
    )
)
```

and data is dynamically coming form database. Pls help me

Comment: what you have done so far Mohit?

Comment: @diEcho I tried so hard to do but at the end i did't get the result  i tried and get this result Array
(
    [days] => Array
        (
            [0] => Monday
            [1] => Tuesday
            [2] => Wednesday
            [3] => Friday
            [4] => Saturday
            [5] => Sunday
        )

    [start_time] => Array
        (
            [0] => 11:00 AM
            [1] => 11:00 AM
            [2] => 11:00 AM
            [3] => 12:00 PM
            [4] => 12:00 PM
            [5] => 12:00 PM
        )

)

Comment: Hi mohit, you cannot have a same key inside an array like what you need in output. as day_of_weeks

Comment: add the final query and the result in your question. It would be more helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a complete solution but might give you some idea on how to proceed:

```
$array = array(
  array(
    'day_of_weeks' => 'Monday',
    'start_time' => '6:00 PM',
    'end_time' => '7:00 PM'
  ),
  array(
    'day_of_weeks' => 'Tuesday',
    'start_time' => '6:00 PM',
    'end_time' => '7:00 PM'
  ),
  array(
    'day_of_weeks' => 'Friday',
    'start_time' => '5:00 PM',
    'end_time' => '6:00 PM'
  )
);
$result = array();

// walk over each element of the original array
array_walk($array, function(&$item, $key) use (&$result) {
   // if the key denoted by `start_time` exists append the `day_of_weeks`
   if(array_key_exists($item['start_time'], $result)) {
      $result[$item['start_time']]['day_of_weeks'][] = $item['day_of_weeks'];
   } else {
      // make `day_of_weeks` an array that can hold more values
      $result[$item['start_time']] = array(
        'start_time' => $item['start_time'],
        'end_time' => $item['end_time'],
        'day_of_weeks' => array($item['day_of_weeks'])
      );
   } 
});

// the output of $result would be
Array
(
  [6:00 PM] => Array
  (
        [start_time] => 6:00 PM
        [end_time] => 7:00 PM
        [day_of_weeks] => Array
        (
           [0] => Monday
           [1] => Tuesday
        )
  )
  [5:00 PM] => Array
  (
        [start_time] => 5:00 PM
        [end_time] => 6:00 PM
        [day_of_weeks] => Array
        (
           [0] => Friday
        )
  )
)
```

Perhaps you should be able to change your mysql query to get the desired output. For example running this query against the following table:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(day_of_weeks) day_of_weeks, 
       start_time, 
       end_time 
FROM data 
GROUP BY start_time 
ORDER BY start_time DESC;

+--------------+------------+----------+
| day_of_weeks | start_time | end_time |
+--------------+------------+----------+
| Monday       | 6:00 PM    | 7:00 PM  |
| Tuesday      | 6:00 PM    | 7:00 PM  |
| Wednesday    | 6:00 PM    | 7:00 PM  |
| Friday       | 5:00 PM    | 6:00 PM  |
| Saturday     | 5:00 PM    | 6:00 PM  |
| Sunday       | 5:00 PM    | 6:00 PM  |
+--------------+------------+----------+
```

The above example would return all days belonging to the same `start_time` separated by a `,` character. Note that the value of `end_time` is not really used, this is also true for the previous example using `array_walk()`.

```
+--------------------------+------------+----------+
| day_of_weeks             | start_time | end_time |
+--------------------------+------------+----------+
| Monday,Tuesday,Wednesday | 6:00 PM    | 7:00 PM  |
| Friday,Saturday,Sunday   | 5:00 PM    | 6:00 PM  |
+--------------------------+------------+----------+
```

You could then get each day using `explode()` or similar:

```
foreach($results as $record) {
  $days = explode(",", $record['day_of_weeks'];
}
```

Comment: @MohitJain - Don't know if it will help, but I added a mysql solution that might do the job.

Comment: thanks again for sql query but your code is worked for me..no need to modify my sql query

Comment: @MohitJain - Just added it as an alternate solution.

Answer (score 1):

First, you can't have multiple differing values for `day_of_weeks` as you have written in your desired output, however you can make `day_of_weeks` an array that holds the names of the days.

Also, since it appears you are using `start_time` and `end_time` as your unique key in your desired output, I would recommend using them in the array key itself to simply your program.

So that gives us:

```
$output_array = array();
foreach ($input_array as $data_item) {
    $time_key = $data_item['start_time'] . ' - ' . $data_item['end_time'];
    if (isset($output_array[$time_key]['day_of_weeks'])) {
        $output_array[$time_key]['day_of_weeks'][] = $data_item['day_of_weeks'];
    } else {
        $output_array[$time_key] = array(
            'day_of_weeks' => array($data_item['day_of_weeks']),
            'start_time'   => $data_item['start_time'],
            'end_time'     => $data_item['end_time'],
        );
    }
}
```

This will result in:

```
Array(
    ['6:00 PM - 7:00 PM'] => Array
    (
        [day_of_weeks] => Array(
            [0] => Monday,
            [1] => Tuesday,
            [2] => Wednesday,
        ),
        [start_time] => 6:00 PM
        [end_time] => 7:00 PM
    )
    ['5:00 PM - 6:00 PM'] => Array
    (
        [day_of_weeks] => Array(
            [0] => Friday,
            [1] => Saturday,
            [2] => Sunday,
        ),
        [start_time] => 5:00 PM
        [end_time] => 6:00 PM
    )
)
```

Comment: you solution  give me last value of the array like in day_of_weeks Wednesday and Sunday

Comment: after modifying your code i almost got the result but above answer give me whole solution